# Optimising Angle Code in Qiskit - Using the QAOAVarForm

Tags: programming, qiskit

I’ve got a bit of an elongated plea for aid here!
I’ve got some code that finds the optimum angles for QAOA on the Maximum Independent Set Problem. It does however seem about ~10x slower than related code that solves the Maxcut Problem.
The issue I think arises from the fact I use `QAOAVarForm.construct_circuit()` to generate my circuit whereas the Maxcut program ‘manually’ places in the RX, RZ gates, etc. I’ve made two notebooks that compare the two approaches side by side in-depth:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xad0fcl49dbesqw/AABcNSBakS8r21Jh_3SOBaTNa?dl=0

(I’ve also included an image from `snakeviz` which shows that the problem is coming from `pauli_trotter_evolution` script. And for that matter the cProfile Data for this too, under the filename ‘Benchmarking_with_COBYLA’)

Here is the engine of my poorly performing code (this is certainly not all the functions required to make it work, those can be found in the notebooks!). Am I doing something incredibly inefficient? Is there a way that speeds up my code? Or would the best be to just manually create the circuit?

```
def quantum_operator_for_graph(Graph,model_name):
    '''
    Generates the quanutm object to be passed to the optimal angles function
    '''
    qp = QuadraticProgram()
    qp.from_docplex(new_docplex_generator(Graph,model_name)) # Putting in Graph
    quantum_operator, offset = qp.to_ising()
    return quantum_operator


def get_qaoa_circuit_sv(var_form,p, theta):
    '''
    Supplies the circuit from var_form to be used in the optimisation stage of the program
    '''
    var_qc = var_form.construct_circuit(theta)  # cost operator put in first, then after p the mixer p angles
    return var_qc


def get_black_box_objective_sv(G,p,var_form,seed =10):
    backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
    def f(theta):
        quantum_circuit = get_qaoa_circuit_sv(var_form,p,theta)
        statevector = execute(quantum_circuit, backend, seed_simulator=seed).result().get_statevector()
        # return the energy
        return compute_mwis_energy_sv(get_adjusted_state(statevector), G)
    return f


def get_optimal_angles(Graph,p, quantum_operator, initial_starting_points,seed):
    '''
    This performs the classical-quantum interchange, improving the values of beta and gamma by reducing the value of
    < beta, gamma | -  C | beta, gamma > (Note Negative Sign). Returns the best angles found and the objective value this refers to.
    Starting points for the angles are randomly distributed across the interval specified.
    '''
    var_form = QAOAVarForm(quantum_operator, p)
    objective_function= get_black_box_objective_sv(Graph,p,var_form,seed)
    optimiser_function =  minimize(objective_function, initial_starting_points, method='COBYLA', options={'maxiter':500})
    best_angles = optimiser_function.x
    objective_value = optimiser_function.fun
    return best_angles,objective_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing all your code. I have looked through it, run both notebooks, and can confirm the difference in the run times. Since you have pretty large amount of the code I have not studied everything till the last line, but I came up with a suspicion when I looked at the Ruslan's code. The profiler output just confirmed what I suspected. Yes, you are right, the problem is in `QAOAVarForm.construct_circuit()` and the way how a QAOA circuit is constructed there. As I recall, the implementation relies on `PauliTrotterEvolution` to support operators and it is slow. Since you construct a new var form on each iteration, the overall optimization procedure is slow also.

If you could use `QAOA` directly, as it is designed, then you could speed up your code significantly. In this case var form is created one time per run.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for looking through my code - how does the `QAOA` method then optimise angles ?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I understood the question. `QAOA` is based on `VQE` which, in turns, has `compute_minimum_eigenvalue` where a parameterized quantum circuit is built one time per problem and then finally an optimizer is called.